# join one row from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with a sql query to do the following:

I need to select all products from products table and for each product i need to join a main image (all columns) from images table. Product images table contains image-product relations and a column sortWeight. Main image is the one with the smallest sortWeight.

To get the main product image, i'd do this:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE product=SOME_PRODUCT ORDER BY sortWeight ASC LIMIT 1;
```

To get all products:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

Now i need to join these two somehow, but the problem is i don't know how to bypass a limitation in the following:

```
SELECT P.* FROM products AS P 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM images AS I WHERE I.product=P.id ORDER BY sortWeight ASC LIMIT 1) AS I1
```

The problem is MySQL does not know what P.id is inside the subquery. I've also tried it like this:

```
SELECT P.* FROM products AS P 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM images AS I WHERE ORDER BY sortWeight ASC LIMIT 1) AS I1 ON (I1.product = P.id)
```

but i don't think this gives an accurate result since there's a limit in subquery and it may select the image from another product with smaller sortWeight.

Can anyone help me rewrite this? Thank you.

Comment: a) What error are you getting, if any? b) If no error, what result are you seeing and why is it wrong? c) I think the answer is far simpler than you indicate. Look into regular join syntax and I think you will find your answer. Something like "select p.*, i.* from products p inner join images i on i.product_id = p.product_id)"

Comment: @MJB If you can find a way to do this without an subquery select, please post it.  I've been bashing my head to figure a more elegant solution as mysql can't optimize on subqueries.  However it looks right now Michal Powaga has the only solution, using a sub query.

Comment: @Ray: I probably did not spend enough time on it, as it was not clear to me what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to join it to subquery that returns images with  smallest (`min`) sortWeight for each `product`.

This returns smallest sortWeight for each product:

```
select product, min(sortWeight) as sortWeight
from images
group by product
```

this is combined version:

```
SELECT P.*, i.*
FROM products AS P 
left join images as i on p.id = i.product
LEFT JOIN (
    select product, min(sortWeight) as sortWeight
    from images
    group by product
) t on t.product = i.product and i.sortWeight = t.sortWeight
```

Comment: Thank you, Michal. Would've never thought of this without your help.